# Can I end a sentence with "<x> may jeopardize."?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs

Can I say the following?

1. If we don't fix this problem now, then our plan may jeopardize.

Comment: "..then our plans *may be in* jeopardy."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sentence improperly treats *jeopardize* as an intransitive verb meaning *come into jeopardy*—that is, become exposed to risk. But *jeopardize* is a transitive verb meaning *put [something] into jeopardy*—that is, expose [something] to risk.

What you want to say is something like

> Not fixing this problem now may jeopardize our plan.

Comment: No need for such a radical rewrite - there's nothing wrong with *If we don't fix this problem now, then our plan may be jeopardized.* (or *...may be [put] in jeopardy*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Your comment seems like the summary of a good answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers True, I recast the *if* clause; but passivizing an active main clause feels to me like a more "radical" rewrite.

Comment: @Jasper: I think it's effectively "writing advice" when we get to that level (the essence of the On Topic aspect of the answer being "*jeopardize* is a transitive verb"). On reflection, I take StoneyB's point that *structurally*, converting the first element to a gerund noun phrase (so it can serve as the *subject* of the verb under scrutiny) is a more direct way of fixing the problem (the problem being that ***our plan*** cannot validly be the subject of the verb ***jeopardize*** in this context, it has to be the direct object).